# Вынос PHP для безопасности

Tags: php, безопасность

Крайне нежелательно, если сторонними людьми будут увидены исходники файлов (к примеру, при DDoS'е, если PHP интерпретатор падает, то можно просто читать/скачивать файлы), поэтому я придумал сделать так: большинство файлов php, которые открываются в браузере, в себе имеют в основном require общего html заголовка и require файла, в котором содержание, которое должно было быть в этом файле.
Но все те файлы (с реальным содержанием) находятся 9в отличие от открываемых браузером внешних) в пределах папки, к которой .htaccess'ом закрыт доступ пользователям, то есть так всё нормально, а если интерпретатор не будет работать, к примеру, то во внешнем доступном файле самого содержания не видно будет ведь. Так стоит делать?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вам глянуть как реализовано большинство php фреймворков, многие вопросы отпадут сами собой..

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю, попробую разобраться с каким-нибудь.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, @culebre:
ну да, это всё хорошо, но я не понимаю, для чего мне модель MVC? И, она мне как-то больше представляется уместной для C, Delphi, и им подобных, но не для скриптового PHP.
И, главное, у меня же нет сейчас проблем, в смысле меня устраивает моя текущая система (которая не построена по принципам MVC), так что не знаю.
Или ключевые слова "у меня же нет _сейчас_ проблем"?)

Comment: Расскажите это работодателям...

Comment: Но сейчас же я работаю не на работодателей.

Comment: Ну вы задали вопрос, вам ответили, будете вы брать во внимание наши ответы или нет - дело ваше, в чем проблема то? мы вас ни к чему не принуждаем...

Comment: Нет, конечно, спасибо большое за все ответы на мои вопросы))
Просто я так и не могу понять, _как_ использовать MVC, на примере простой задачи...хотя для простых он, наверное, и не нужен?)
Пока что гуглю.
Даже если он мне сейчас не нужен прямо, то раз это такая известная штука, надо заставить себя разобраться с этим, у меня так)

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что паттерн MVC это из другой оперы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задаетесь таким вопросом то надо копать в сторону Model View Controller (MVC) и функционалом веб-сервера mod_rewrite. Это даст реальное усиление безопасности обеспечив единую "точку входа" на веб-ресурс, исключая полностью возможность обращения к другим файлам. А MVC(парадигма разделения модель-представление-контроллер) в свою очередь позволяет грамотно разделять функционал скриптов по их назначению.
Соответственно как было упомянуто [[@alexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope) есть куча фреймворков на php, большинство используют mvc:
[Например такой обзор](http://sanchiz.net/post/16)

Comment: Честно, о таком ещё не задумывался.
А конкретно моя задумка, её можно использовать, или это плохо?

Comment: В правильном направлении идут ваши мысли, почитайте про mvc + mod_rewrite и узнаете много нового.

Comment: @culebre - единая точка входа не имеет никакого отношения к MVC, это шаблон FrontController...

Comment: Да я и не говорю, что она имеет прямое отношение, просто часто используются в связке.

Comment: так и пишете `@Юзер` == @Юзер

Comment: Хм, спасибо, что-то так же пробовал - не получалось, наверное имя пользователя неправильно набрал.

Comment: Посмотрел немного на эту тему.
К стыду своему, так и не могу понять, что именно дадут мне фреймворки((

Comment: Вас никто не заставляет их использовать, структуру изучите хотябы...

Comment: Просто я в принципе не понимаю, вот что он мне даст (ну я прочитал про ускорение разработки), но мне хочется конкретный пример.
Изучить структуру - это вы имеете в виду, чтобы посмотреть MVC?

Comment: Так, ладно, буду ещё изучать, пока что я ещё не понял все, сложновато для новичка.
Но вообще, можно пока остановиться ни используемом мной?

Comment: Принцип прост есть контроллер он должен быть максимально легким и собственно он своего рода маршрутизатор запросов, авторегулировщик если лучше подойдет такое сравнение, вьювер занимается отображением данных - весь GUI на нем, и контроллер это движок извлекает данные из баз, обрабатывает их и отдает вьюверу. Не помню, где читал если честно, но помню точно, что использовалось выражение Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers

Comment: контроллер он должен быть максимально легким...<br>
@culebre - где вы такое прочитали?

Answer (score 1):

Частенько используется подобный вариант:
В файлах которые **должны** быть доступны напрямую, пишут:

```
define('MY_ENGINE', true);
```

А в тех, которые **НЕ должны**:

```
if (!defined('MY_ENGINE')) die("Hacking attempt!");
```

Comment: А, ну такое видел, я то не совсем про это.
Файлы, которые не должны быть доступны напрямую, просто будут всё равно в пределах закрытой директории.